# Cannot understand the code for removing words with numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to remove words with numbers. After research I understood that

```
 s = "ABCD abcd AB55 55CD A55D 5555"
>>> re.sub("\S*\d\S*", "", s).strip()
```

This code works to solve my situation

However, I am not able to understand how this code works. I know about regex and I know individually \d recognizes all the numbers [0-9]. \S is for white spaces. and * is 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left

```
"\S*\d\S*"
```

This part I am not able to understand

But I am not sure I understand how this code identifies AB55.

Can anyone please explain to me? Thanks

Comment: `\S` matches a non whitespace char instead of white spaces.

Comment: No `\S` is the *opposite* of `\s`, so all except whitespaces.

Comment: it's `\s` for whitespace, but `\S` for non whitespace. note that it's capitals. Also, your 1 stop shop for regexes: https://regex101.com/r/95HsD1/1

Answer (score 1):

this replaces a digit with any non-space symbols around with empty string ""

the AB55 is viewed like : `AB are \S*, 5 is \d, 5 is \S`*

55CD : `empty string is \S*,  5 is \d, 5CD is \S*`

A55D : `A is \S*,  5 is \d, 5D is \S*`

5555 : `empty string is \S*,  5 is \d, 555 is \S*`

The `re.sub("\S*\d\S*", "", s)` replaces all this substrings to empty string "" and .strip() is useless since it removes whitespace at the begin and end of the previous result

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the code. `\S` is the *opposite* of `\s`: it matches with everything *except* whitespace.

Since the *Kleene star* (`*`) is greedy, it thus means that it aims to match as much non-space characters as possible, followed by a digit followed by as much non-space characters as possible. It will thus match a full word, where at least *one* character is a digit.

All these matches are then replaced by the empty string, and therefore removed from the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Your code first matches 0+ times non whitespace chars `\S*` (where `\s*` matches whitespace chars) and will match all the way until the end of the "word". Then it backtracks to match a digit and and again match 0+ non whitespace chars.

The pattern will for example also match a single digit.

You could slightly optimize the pattern to first match not a whitespace char or a digit `[^\s\d]*` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to prevent the first `\S*` match the whole word.

```
[^\s\d]*\d\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeF0Cv/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is how your `regex` works, you mention about `\S` for white spaces. But it is not.

[image]

This is what python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto) mention about `\s` and `\S`

> \s
>
> Matches any whitespace character; this is equivalent to the class [ \t\n\r\f\v].
>
> \S
>
> Matches any non-whitespace character; this is equivalent to the class [^ \t\n\r\f\v].

This is with `\s` which is for whitespace characters.

[image]

and you'll get an output like this,

```py
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = "ABCD abcd AB55 55CD A55D 5555"
>>> re.sub("\s*\d\s*", "", s).strip()
'ABCD abcd ABCD AD'
```